# Mailto: tag won't dissappear

Tags: macos, bug

I've had this problem a few times in the past. How do you get rid of a mailto: or alt tag that won't disappear <del>from the Google screen.</del>

[image: mail to tag]

EDIT

@Buscar - it wasn't just Google, it was appearing over every window Chrome or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd> and left-clicking on the application (Chrome in my case) got rid of it for me.

Comment: @Patience it won't let me for 2 days.